# CSS :not selector not working?

Tags: css

I've made this screenshot. For some reason the `:not` selector isn't working?
I just don't really get why it isn't working, even though the `ul` element does have the `webmedia-gallery` class.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/gof7oz7e/
[image: screen]

Comment: I believe you can't target multiple :not elements in one statement

Comment: why `:not` create a fiddle or put some code rather than an image!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to chain your `not` conditions

```
ul:not(.languages):not(.webmedia-gallery) li:before {
  ...
}
```

in fact, if you split your `not` conditions into multiple selectors, as you did, at least one of them will match. By chaining the conditions you are looking for a list whose classes are not nor `.languages` neither `.webmedia-gallery`

> [Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjKRKp)

Comment: Either I'm doing it wrong or it doesn't make any difference: https://jsfiddle.net/smfka5g6/

Comment: @SheperdOfFire looks fine in Chrome.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Oh shoot... Sorry, my mistake. Mixed up a few lists. The JSfiddle is indeed correct.

Comment: An additional question, now I have this:
`nav:not(.navigationobject) ul li:before, ul:not(.languages):not(.webmedia-gallery) li:before`
This is generated from scss, is there any way to combine the 2, because like this it is not working

Comment: you need to change the sass source, in order to create a chained output

Answer (score 0):

You are using two selectors with `:not` for one rule, which means one of them is always matching.

The provided fiddle is working fine. Update a bit to have multiple ul's to see how it's working: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smfka5g6/1/)